# Segmentation fault with strtok and storing into variables?

Tags: c

I'm trying to use "strtok" to split a user input into 4 parts. So one example string looks like "john 1.3 2.4 3".

I want to store the first in a character array, the second and third as a floating point variable, and the last as an integer.

At first I tried using scanf and storing the variables into the desired locations.
I was advised that using fgets and splitting the string is better. My code looks like this:

```
    char Input[4];
    char names[5];
    struct numbers
    {
        float start;
        float end;
        int rows;
    }values;

    fgets(Input, sizeof(Input), stdin);
    token = strtok(Input, " ");

    strcpy(names, token);
    values.start = atof(strtok(NULL, " "));
    values.end = atof(strtok(NULL, " "));
    values.rows= atoi(strtok(NULL, " "));
```

I get a segmentation fault after entering the user input.
How can I solve this?
Is it better to just use scanf?

Comment: You have to enlarge the size of your Input array. It only holds 4 characters. If the input is of the form you described, the input string won't fit in.

Comment: Can you copy-paste the actual code that you tried? Your structure definition is just wrong.

Comment: @MananVora It is not a member of your struct because it is not there in your struct. Look as your struct definition - it has two `end`

Comment: Okay my code is in a module so I'll post the relevant items

Comment: Yeah, seems like this needs an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

```
char Input[40];
char names[5];
char *token;
struct numbers
{
    float start;
    float end;
    int rows;
}values;

fgets(Input, sizeof(Input), stdin);
token = strtok(Input, " ");

strcpy(names, token);

values.start = atof(strtok(NULL, " "));
values.end = atof(strtok(NULL, " "));
values.rows= atoi(strtok(NULL, " "));

printf("%s\n %.1f\n %.1f\n %d",names,values.start,values.end,values.rows);
```

Increase the size of the Input array.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: Please increase the size of "Input".

> Reason for the issue: As per your code "Input" can have only four
>   chars. So, when the input string exceeds 4 chars, "strtok" tries to
>   read the data out of boundary and it can cause segmentation fault.

Comment: Hi, I've tried increasing the size of Input, but it still gives me a segfault?

Comment: Could you please share your code again? Try with the size of 100